# terraform aws_secretsmanager_secret_version set base64encode(file("./src/secret.json")) as the value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to setup a key value secret in AWS Secrets Manager with terraform.
Now I would like to replace the string "AzureDiamond" with a base64 encoded json object.
Can you help me how I could replace the mentioned string with the value returned by this base64encode(file("./src/secret.json"))

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "testtools" {
    secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.testtools.id
    secret_string = "{\"config\":\"AzureDiamond\"}"
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to do? Its not clear.

Comment: In the end I would like to have the secret_string look like so....
`secret_string = "{\"config\":base64encode(file("./src/secret.json"))}"`
The key of the secret should be "config" and the value of the secret should be the base64 encoded json from the file secret.json

Comment: I've noticed that almost your questions got answered yet only one was accepted. Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I accepted them now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use [filebase64](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/filebase64.html) with `jsonencode`:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "testtools" {
    secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.testtools.id
    secret_string = jsonencode({config = filebase64("./src/secret.json")})
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help! That is exactly what I wanted to achieve..

Comment: @Kaliph No problem. Glad it helped:-)